# jquery how to override the class method?

Tags: jquery, overriding, extend

Looks like this question is popular, but there is no jQuery version.

I have two classes the second is extended from the first one.

The extension method [is copied from here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/class-inheritance-with-jquery-extend).

```
function UIButton(o){
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') $.extend(true, this, o); 
    this.setOutput=function(divname){
      alert("first");
    }
}

function UIButton2(o) {
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') $.extend(true, this, o);
    this.setOutput=function(divname) {
        alert("second");
    }
    return new UIButton(this);
}
```

According to [the jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

The second object's method should override the first object's method (with same name) by using `$.extend()`.

However I check it in the html and found the first object's function still work like good. (Alert "first"...) This makes its subclass cannot override the function.

So I want to ask, how this happen and how to solve it. I want to alert "second"......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend first, and then you set the new `setOutput` (*so you overwrite the extended method*).

If you change the order it will work..

```
function UIButton(o){
    this.setOutput=function(divname){
      alert("first");
    }
    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') $.extend(true, this, o); 
}

function UIButton2(o) {
    this.setOutput=function(divname) {
        alert("second");
    }

    if (typeof(o) != 'undefined') $.extend(true, this, o);
    return new UIButton(this);
}
```

(*only needed in the `UIButton` for this example, but i added it to both for future usage*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/R26ec/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery proxy method to override class
Ref: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Context.2C_Call_and_Apply

For example

```
(function() {
   // log all calls to setArray
   var proxied = jQuery.fn.setArray;
   jQuery.fn.setArray = function() {
   console.log( this, arguments );
   return proxied.apply( this, arguments );
  };
})();
```